# Webscraping a page along with browser extension data using Python

Tags: python, html

I am trying to get text data of a webpage as it would look on my browser.
My Problem is that I'm also using an extension for that webpage whose given data(text that shows up due to it) is also to be collected.
I know urllib but it only collects the normal webpage data not the extension generated data.
So any help on how to collect that data?
Also I'm asking is this even possible?

Comment: Read about `selenium`. It got a chrome extensions support as well

Comment: Yeah, Selenium should do it as @MyNick pointed out. You might also find selectors useful.

Answer (score 0):

Using Selenium, you can load and scrape a page with an actual browser. So you should be able to get your extension working on the said browser which will give you the text you want to scrape. With Selenium you can wait for various components to load before executing the scrape.

This is the full documentation:
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

The wait feature can be found here:
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html